# In which database JpaRepository uses by default?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When we using methods that come from JpaRepository like save, in which database spring boot use?
and how can we change the default database if necessary?

```
@Repository
  
// Interface
public interface FooRepository
    extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the database which you have configured in your properties file. You can change the database using the following properties(MySQL example):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo_example
spring.datasource.username=todouser
spring.datasource.password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Comment: For me the properties file does not contain a specific database-related configuration,In such a case, is h2 the default one?

Comment: Ok, so you're using H2 in-memory that has default settings. Please check section "Spring Boot Default H2 Database Settings" from - https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

The database url & credentials can be defined in your application.properties file like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaName
spring.datasource.username=yourUsername
spring.datasource.password=yourPassword
```

In case you are using multiple databases, you can set one of them as default and specify when you want to access the second one. You can check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) on how to do it.